# How do you prove$(a^m)^{-1} = (a^{-1})^m$ for a being any non-zero real and m being a positive integer from the axioms of real numbers?

Tags: analysis, axioms

How do you prove $(a^m)^{-1} = (a^{-1})^m$ for $a$ being any non-zero real and $m$ being a positive integer, from the axioms of real numbers only?

Comment: Depends heavily on how you define $x^{-1}$, but most of the time, it's proved by induction on $m$.

Comment: Hint: what is $a^m\cdot(a^{-1})^m$?

Comment: starting from the commutativity of the real numbers product, which is an axiom, then it's strictly a notation matter

Answer (score 2):

You should use induction. The base case is $m=1$ and the relation to be proved is
$$
(a^1)^{-1}=(a^{-1})^1
$$
which is true.

Suppose the statement holds for $m$; then
\begin{align}
(a^{m+1})^{-1}
&=(a^ma)^{-1} &&\text{definition of powers}\\
&=(a^m)^{-1}a^{-1} &&\text{because $(xy)^{-1}=x^{-1}y^{-1}$} \\
&=(a^{-1})^ma^{-1} &&\text{induction hypothesis} \\
&=(a^{-1})^{m+1} &&\text{definition of powers}
\end{align}

The proof of $(xy)^{-1}=x^{-1}y^{-1}$:
\begin{align}
(xy)(x^{-1}y^{-1})
&=(yx)(x^{-1}y^{-1}) &&\text{commutativity} \\
&=y\bigl(x(x^{-1}y^{-1})\bigr) &&\text{associativity} \\
&=y\bigl((xx^{-1})y^{-1}\bigr) &&\text{associativity} \\
&=\dots \\
&=1
\end{align}
which you can finish.

Answer (score 0):

From the existence of the inverse we have that, for $a \ne0$ there exists $b$ such that $a^mb=1$.

For $m=1$ this gives $ab=1 \Rightarrow b=a^{-1}$ .

Now suppose that $a^mb^m=1$ than:
$$
a^{m+1}b^{m+1}=a^mab^mb=a^mb^mab=a^mb^m=1
$$

and this prove, by induction, the statement.

Answer (score -1):

$$\forall a,m\in\mathbb{R}$$
Step one: I prove $(a^{m})^{-1}=(a^{-1})^{m}$
$$(x^n)^m=x^{nm}$$
Then
$$(a^{m})^{-1}=(a^{-1})^{m}\Rightarrow a^{m\cdot-1}=a^{-1\cdot m}\Rightarrow a^{-m}=a^{-m}$$

Step two: $a^{-m}>0$
$$a^{-m}=a^{-1\cdot m}=(a^{-1})^{m}=(\frac{1}{a})^{m}=(\frac{1}{a^{m}}) \Longrightarrow(\frac{1}{a^{m}})>0$$